# Subgraph isomorphism in NetworkX graphs from python ASTs

Tags: python, networkx, abstract-syntax-tree, isomorphism

I have two python files. I generated two NetworkX graphs just traversing the ASTs of the files. I want to check - is there a sub-graph of one graph isomorphic to another one?

***Python files are presented below -***

**whiletest.py**

```
a= 10
while(a <= 0):
    if a == 5:
        print(a)
        a += 1
print("exited")
```

**whiletestchanged.py**

```
a= 10
# ANBD
'''
Test Someting
'''
while(b <= 0): #   print("a is:", a)    
    if a == 5:   # if a is 5, then break  
        print(a) 
    a += 1
    # a += 1 
print("exited")
```

***Class for making the NXgraphs from the ASTs***

```
class GetNXgraphFromAST(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []
        self.graph = nx.Graph()

    def generic_visit(self, stmt):
        node_name = stmt
        parent_name = None

        if self.stack:
            parent_name = self.stack[-1]

        self.stack.append(node_name)
        self.graph.add_node(node_name)

        if parent_name:
            self.graph.add_edge(node_name, parent_name)

        super(self.__class__, self).generic_visit(stmt)
        self.stack.pop()
```

***Their graph representations are presented below -***

**whiletest.png**

[image]

**whiletestchanged.png**

[image]

***The code to check isomorphism -***

```
nodesoriginal = ast.parse(srcOriginal)
nodesbackport = ast.parse(srcBackport)
OriginalNXGraphIni = GetNXgraphFromAST()
BackportNXGraphIni = GetNXgraphFromAST()
OriginalNXGraphIni.visit(nodesoriginal) 
BackportNXGraphIni.visit(nodesbackport)
OriginalNXGraph = OriginalNXGraphIni.graph
BackportNXGraph = BackportNXGraphIni.graph

isomorphicSUbGraphs = isomorphism.GraphMatcher(OriginalNXGraph, BackportNXGraph)
for subGraph in isomorphicSUbGraphs.subgraph_isomorphisms_iter():
    subGraph = subGraph
    break
```

But it does not detect any sub-isomorphic graph. Am I making any mistakes? Thanks in advance for any helps regarding this.

Comment: Could you provide runnable code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below accepts two Python source strings, checks if any isomorphic subgraphs exist, and then prints the results:

```
import ast
import collections

def tree_attrs(tree):
   #extract AST node's attributes for matching later
   return (t:=type(tree)).__name__, \
    [a for a in t._fields if not isinstance(getattr(tree, a), 
                                                        (ast.AST, list))], \
    [i for i in t._fields if isinstance(getattr(tree, i), (ast.AST, list))]
    
def build_graph(tree, d1, d2, p = []):
   #recursively build subgraph from a starting AST node
   #potential child nodes can be discovered by checking d1 and d2
   if str(attrs:=tree_attrs(tree)) in d2 and \
      any(p == p1[-1*len(p):] or not p for _, p1 in d2[str(attrs)]):
      ast_attrs = {}
      for i in attrs[2]:
         if isinstance(v:=getattr(tree, i), list):
            ast_attrs[i] = [result for j in v if (result:=build_graph(j, d1, d2, p+[type(tree).__name__])) is not None]
         elif (result:=build_graph(v, d1, d2, p+[type(tree).__name__])) is not None:
            ast_attrs[i] = result
      return type(tree)(**{i:getattr(tree, i) for i in attrs[1]}, **ast_attrs, **{i:getattr(tree, i, 0) 
             for i in type(tree)._attributes})   

def walk(tree, p = []):
   #get all AST nodes from the .py source, along with its ancestor hierarchy
   yield tree, p
   for i in tree._fields:
     if isinstance(v:=getattr(tree, i), list):
       for j in v:
          yield from walk(j, p + [type(tree).__name__])
     elif isinstance(v, ast.AST):
        yield from walk(v, p + [type(tree).__name__])

def subgraphs(s1, s2):
   #build AST node lookup from both .py sources
   #these lookups are later used to find valid children for any given AST node
   d1, d2 = collections.defaultdict(list), collections.defaultdict(list)
   for i, p in walk(ast.parse(s1)):
      d1[str(tree_attrs(i))].append((i, p))
   for i, p in walk(ast.parse(s2)):
      d2[str(tree_attrs(i))].append((i, p))
   return [build_graph(i, d1, d2) for i in ast.walk(ast.parse(s1))]
   
def valid_py_subgraphs(sub_g):
   result = []
   for i in sub_g:
      try:
         if (r:=ast.unparse(i)):
            result.append(r)
      except: pass
   return result
```

---

```
s1 = """
a= 10
while(b <= 0):
    if a == 5:
        print(a)
        a += 1
print("exited")
"""
s2 = """a= 10
# ANBD
'''
Test Someting
'''
while(a <= 0): #   print("a is:", a)    
    if a == 5:   # if a is 5, then break  
        print(a) 
    a += 1
    # a += 1 
print("exited")"""
sub_g = valid_py_subgraphs(subgraphs(s1, s2))
print(bool(sub_g))
print('='*20)
for i in sub_g:
  print(i)
  print('-'*20)
```

Sample output:

```
True
====================
a = 10
while b <= 0:
    if a == 5:
        print(a)
print('exited')
--------------------
a = 10
--------------------
while b <= 0:
    if a == 5:
        print(a)
--------------------
print('exited')
--------------------
a
--------------------
10
--------------------
b <= 0
--------------------
if a == 5:
    print(a)
--------------------
print('exited')
--------------------
a += 1
--------------------
print(a)
--------------------
...
```

---

```
s3 = """
def main(a, b, c):
    return [i for i in range([3, 4])]
"""
s4 = """
def main(a, b, n = 10):
   return [i for i in range([1, 2, 3])]
"""
sub_g = valid_py_subgraphs(subgraphs(s3, s4))
print(bool(sub_g))
for i in sub_g:
  print(i)
  print('-'*20)
```

Sample Output:

```
True
====================
def main(a, b, c):
    return [i for i in range([3, 4])]
--------------------
a, b, c
--------------------
return [i for i in range([3, 4])]
--------------------
a
--------------------
b
--------------------
c
--------------------
[i for i in range([3, 4])]
--------------------
 for i in range([3, 4])
--------------------
i
--------------------
range([3, 4])
--------------------
range
--------------------
[3, 4]
--------------------
3
--------------------
4
--------------------
```

Comment: Hi @Ajax1234, the solution works for node-induced isomorphism but does not work for edge-induced isomorphism. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: And I also need unmatched statements rather than matched ones. Having difficulties to extract them with the solution.

Comment: @joydeba Can you post samples of your data and desired output?

Comment: Hi @Ajax1234, I just changed the input pys. You can see the while stmt has now a different variable (i.e., b, actually a mistake). Thus node value should be matched with types rather than concrete matching. I just want to match the code structure thus graph edge and node type are important in matching. Thanks.

Comment: @joydeba Please see my recent edit.